# polynomials with no repeated factors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Assume that $F(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients that is "square-free" over $\mathbb Q$, i.e. it does not have repeated polynomial factors whose coefficients are in $\mathbb Q$. Can we prove that for all large primes $\ell$ the polynomial when reduced modulo $\ell$ will not have repeated polynomial factors in $\mathbb F_\ell[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$?

Comment: Use discriminants with respect to each variable…

Comment: hmm, that sounds interesting. Can you give one or two details please? How would that work for the polynomial $x^2+ y 10!$ for example?

Comment: what do you mean by "$y10!$"?

Comment: $y$ multiplied by the number $10!$, i.e. the factorial of $10$. Thanks!

Comment: $F(x_1)g(x_1) + F'(x_1)h(x_1) = n$ for some integer $n$. If $F(x_1) $ has a repeated factor in $\mathbb{F}_l$, then $\gcd(F(x_1), F'(x_1))$ is not a constant. It is only possible if $l \mid n$.

Comment: But this proof works only for 1 variable polynomials probably.

Comment: @DenisShatrov Thank you! Yes you are right that it is not clear how to generalise this for more variables.